# Expected value of an account after $k$ years, if the value doubles or halves with equal probability?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

**The Problem (Source: https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf)**

Note: I abridged the problem to take out the fluff. It's #19.32 in the link above.

> You put $\$1,000,000$ dollars into an account. Each year, the money in your account will double or halve with equal probability, and each year you will get a dividend equal to 10% of the money in your account.

> What is the expected number of dollars in your account at the end of $k$ years? Write a simple formula in terms of $k$.

**My Solution**

Define random variable $X_i$ as follows:

$$X_i = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if the money doubles at the end of year $i$, probability = $\frac 1 2$} \\ 1/2 & \text{if the money halves at the end of year $i$, probability = $\frac 1 2$}\end{cases}.$$

Let $D$ denote the amount of money after $k$ years, $D = X_1 + \ldots + X_k$.

Then the formula is given as

$$\mathbb{E}(D) =  (1,000,000) \prod_{i=1}^k\frac {11} {10} \cdot\mathbb{E}(X_i).$$

I got this general formula after working through a few small examples. For instance, for $k = 2$:

Initial: $1,000,000$; at the end of year $1$, we expect an account balance equal to $\frac{11}{10} \cdot \mathbb{E}(X_1) \cdot 1,000,000$.

At the end of year $2$, we expect an amount of money equal to $\frac{11}{10}\cdot\mathbb{E}(X_2)\cdot\text{the quantity above}$.

And if you repeatedly apply this $k$ times you will get the formula I wrote.

**My Question**

There is no answer key to the book, and I couldn't find anything online for this problem. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Is the dividend paid before the halving/doubling or after?

Comment: @Snoop paid after the halving/doubling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binomial random walk is described by the recursion
$$X_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
2X_n\cdot 1.1=2.2X_n & p=0.5 \\
0.5X_n\cdot 1.1=0.55X_n & p=0.5
\end{cases}$$
By iterating the conditional expected value we obtain
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|X_0]=0.5(2.2\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_0]+0.55\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_0])$$
Finally:
$$y_{n+1}=(0.5\cdot2.2+0.5\cdot 0.55)y_n$$
$$\implies y_k=(0.5\cdot2.2+0.5\cdot 0.55)^ky_0,k\geq 1$$